# Algorithms for encryptor in RSA

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, gcd-and-lcm, cryptography, totient-function

In RSA we denote encryptor as $E$ such that:
$$\gcd(E,\phi(p,q))=1\tag{where $p,q$ are primes}$$

I know if for all prime factors $c$ of $\phi(p,q)$, $c \not\mid E$, that we can choose this $E$ as a encryptor, since in this case gcd is $1$.

---

What I did is for example:
$$p=331,q=233,\phi(p,q)=(331-1)\cdot(233-1)=76560$$
Since $76560=2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot11\cdot29$, the smallest $E$ that would work is next prime after $5$ which is $7$.

Basicly, this is like looping though all the primes $P=\{2,3,5,7\cdots\}$, if it's not in the prime factor of $\phi(p,q):F=\{2,3,5,11,29\}$, then it's a valid choice of $E$.

So we can denote the smallest $E$ as the following:
$$\min(P\cap F^c)$$

---

- This is the algorithm i'm using right now, is there better approaches
  to find such $E$ ?
- And there are many choice of $E$, but I don't know smaller $E$
  is better or larger $E$ is better, would there be any difference if I
  pick different $E$ in RSA ?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally we use $\gcd(e,\lambda(n))=1$ as the criterion, where $\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael function of the modulus $n$, for $n=pq$ this equals the least common multiple of $p-1$ and $q-1$, almost always smaller than $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$.

Also, $p$ and $q$ are normally chosen beforehand with the property that $p-1$ and $p+1$ have no small prime factors except (the unavoidable) $2$. This to avoid some attacks.

This means that choosing $e=3$ is then always possible, and this is OK when using proper OAEP padding etc and almost always $e=2^{16}+1$, which are both very efficient for encrypting. If not, try the next prime, e.g.

See the key generation section of [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for more info and references.

Comment: Maybe you should also add that, when using 3 in textbook RSA, cuberoot attack is also possible and many other attacks therefore we use RSA encryption with proper paddings like PKCS#1.5 and OAEP...